# Как можно исправить неправильное формирование обратной польской нотации?

Tags: java, алгоритм, парсер

Пишу постфиксный калькулятор на основе обратной польской нотации. Программа корректно формирует нотацию, если ввести в нее строку с одной тригонометрической формулой или без них. В этом случае считает тоже корректно. Но если передать в класс более сложную формулу, то Обратная польская нотация формируется некорректно.

Сам класс калькулятора содержит такие методы:

```
  public class RPNCalculator extends Object {

private Stack<String> stringStack = new Stack<>();
private String operation = "";
// первый формирует ОПН из формулы
private String formulaToRPN(String formula) {
    String currentStr = "";
    int priority = 0;
    Stack<Character> characterStack = new Stack<>();
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();



    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {
        char ch = formula.charAt(i);
        priority = getPriority(ch);
           // неправильно работает это условие
           if (getPriority(ch)==4) {
            stringBuffer.append(ch);
            operation += stringBuffer.toString();
            if(operation.length() >=3) stringStack.add(operation);
            if (!stringStack.empty() && stringStack.peek().equals(operation)) operation = "";
            if (!stringStack.empty() && currentStr.length() !=0 && currentStr.charAt(currentStr.length()-1) ==' ') currentStr += stringStack.pop();

            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        }
            // далее рабочий код 
            if (priority == 0) currentStr += ch;
            if (priority == 1) {
                characterStack.push(ch);
            }


            if (priority > 1 && priority <4) {
                currentStr += ' ';
                while (!characterStack.empty()) {
                    if (getPriority(characterStack.peek()) >= priority) currentStr += characterStack.pop();
                    else break;
                }
                characterStack.push(ch);
            }

            if (priority == -1) {
                currentStr += ' ';
                while (getPriority(characterStack.peek()) != 1) currentStr += characterStack.pop();
                characterStack.pop();
            }

        }

        while (!characterStack.empty()) currentStr += characterStack.pop();
        while (!stringStack.empty()) currentStr += ' '+ stringStack.pop();


        return currentStr;
    }

    // второй обеспечивает расчет формулы

    private double RPNToAnswer (String rpn){
        String operand = "";
        Stack<Double> doubleStack = new Stack<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rpn.length(); i++) {

            if (rpn.charAt(i) == ' ') continue;

            else if (getPriority(rpn.charAt(i)) == 0) {
                while (rpn.charAt(i) != ' ' && getPriority(rpn.charAt(i)) == 0) {
                    operand += rpn.charAt(i++);
                    if (i == rpn.length()) break;
                }
                doubleStack.push(Double.parseDouble(operand));
                operand = operand.replace(operand, "");
            }
            if (getPriority(rpn.charAt(i)) > 1) {
                double firstOperand =0, secondOperand =0;
                if(!doubleStack.empty()) firstOperand = doubleStack.pop();
                if (!doubleStack.empty())secondOperand = doubleStack.pop();

                if (rpn.charAt(i) == '^') doubleStack.push(Math.pow(firstOperand, secondOperand));
                if (rpn.charAt(i) == '+') doubleStack.push(firstOperand + secondOperand);
                if (rpn.charAt(i) == '-') doubleStack.push(firstOperand - secondOperand);
                if (rpn.charAt(i) == '/') doubleStack.push(firstOperand / secondOperand);
                if (rpn.charAt(i) == '*') doubleStack.push(firstOperand * secondOperand);

                if (rpn.contains("sin")) doubleStack.push(Math.sin(firstOperand));
                if (operation.equals("cos")) doubleStack.push(Math.cos(firstOperand));
                if (operation.equals("tan")) doubleStack.push(Math.tan(firstOperand));
                if (operation.equals("abs")) doubleStack.push(Math.abs(firstOperand));
                if (operation.equals("acos")) doubleStack.push(Math.acos (firstOperand));
                if (operation.equals("asin")) doubleStack.push(Math.asin(firstOperand));
                if (operation.equals("atan")) doubleStack.push(Math.atan(firstOperand));
                if (operation.equals("sqrt")) doubleStack.push(Math.sqrt(firstOperand));


            }


        }

        return doubleStack.pop();
    }

    // определяем приоритет операций
     private int getPriority(char currentCharacter){

     if (Character.isLetter(currentCharacter))            return 4;
else if (currentCharacter =='*'|| currentCharacter=='/')  return 3;
else if (currentCharacter == '+'|| currentCharacter=='-') return 2;
else if (currentCharacter == '(')                         return 1;
else if (currentCharacter ==')')                          return -1;
else                                                      return 0;
}

   // для отрицательных чисел

  private String prepareToCalculate (String formula){
    String preparedFormula ="";

    for (char ch : formula.toCharArray()){
        if (ch =='-'){
            if(formula.indexOf(ch)==0) preparedFormula +='0';
            else if (formula.charAt(formula.indexOf(ch))=='(') preparedFormula +='0';
        }

        preparedFormula +=ch;


    }

    return  preparedFormula;

    }

    // окончательный результат

      public double getAnswer (String formula){
    String preparedFormula = prepareToCalculate(formula);
    String rpn = formulaToRPN(preparedFormula);
    double answer = RPNToAnswer(rpn);

    return answer;
}
}
```

Из-за неправильно работающего условия в первом методе, из строки `"sin(60)+cos(30)^2"`формируется строка `60  sin30 ^2+ cos`, а должна формироваться ОПН. Если не ошибаюсь, то правильной строкой будет: `60 sin 30 cos 2 ^ +`. Прошу помощи в отладке кода.

Для запуска программы:

```
  public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private  static MainWindow mainWindow;
private JButton runButton = new JButton("Пуск");

 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (e.getSource== runButton){
RPNCalculator c = new RPNCalculator();
        System.out.println(c.getAnswer("sin(60)+cos(30)^2"));
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    runButton.addActionListner(this);
    mainWindow.add(runButton);

}
```

Comment: вы уверены что формула должна так  "sin(60)+cos^2(30)" выглядеть, а не так sin(60)+(cos(30))^2 ?

Comment: @Z.John Похоже Вы правы... но все равно формируется строка 60  sin30 ^2+ cos

Comment: @Z.John  вопрос исправил.